# How to Randomize Embedded MP3 Playback in ActionScript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have nicked some code that allows for playback of external MP3s, but it seems that the more files I add, the more temperamental the playback becomes.  Specifically, it seems to truncate the beginning and end of each MP3, and the playback is unpredictable.  I should mention that the MP3s are quite small.  They are individual words that are meant to spurt out a kind of alien poetry when played back randomly.  When I play back the SWF locally off my computer's hard drive, the playback is smooth, but when I test it online, things start to get choppy.  Here's the code I'm using.

```
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.media.SoundChannel;
import flash.events.Event;

 playsong();
//var songs:Array=new Array("part0.mp3","part1.mp3","part2.mp3","part3.mp3","part4.mp3","part5.mp3","part6.mp3","part7.mp3","part8.mp3","part9.mp3","part10.mp3","part11.mp3","part12.mp3","part13.mp3","part14.mp3","part15.mp3","part16.mp3","part17.mp3","part18.mp3","part19.mp3","part20.mp3","part21.mp3","part22.mp3","part23.mp3","part24.mp3","part25.mp3","part26.mp3","part27.mp3","part28.mp3","part29.mp3","part30.mp3","part31.mp3","part32.mp3","part33.mp3","part34.mp3","part35.mp3","part36.mp3","part37.mp3","part38.mp3","part39.mp3","part40.mp3","part41.mp3","part42.mp3","part43.mp3","part44.mp3","part45.mp3","part46.mp3","part47.mp3","part48.mp3","part49.mp3","part50.mp3","part51.mp3","part52.mp3","part53.mp3","part54.mp3","part55.mp3","part56.mp3","part57.mp3","part58.mp3","part59.mp3","part60.mp3","part61.mp3","part62.mp3","part63.mp3","part64.mp3","part65.mp3","part66.mp3","part67.mp3","part68.mp3","part69.mp3","part70.mp3","part71.mp3","part72.mp3","part73.mp3","part74.mp3","part75.mp3","part76.mp3","part77.mp3","part78.mp3","part79.mp3","part80.mp3","part81.mp3","part82.mp3","part83.mp3","part84.mp3","part85.mp3","part86.mp3","part87.mp3","part88.mp3","part89.mp3","part90.mp3","part91.mp3","part92.mp3","part93.mp3","part94.mp3","part95.mp3","part96.mp3","part97.mp3","part98.mp3","part99.mp3","part100.mp3","part101.mp3","part102.mp3","part103.mp3","part104.mp3","part105.mp3","part106.mp3","part107.mp3","part108.mp3","part109.mp3","part110.mp3","part111.mp3","part112.mp3","part113.mp3","part114.mp3","part115.mp3","part116.mp3","part117.mp3","part118.mp3","part119.mp3","part120.mp3","part121.mp3","part122.mp3","part123.mp3","part124.mp3","part125.mp3","part126.mp3");
 var sound:Sound;
 var soundChannel:SoundChannel;
 var randnum:uint;
 function playsong()
 {
 randnum=Math.floor(Math.random()*127);
 sound=new Sound();
 var songs:String= "part" + randnum + ".mp3";  
 sound.load(new URLRequest("parts/"+songs)); 
 soundChannel=sound.play();
 soundChannel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE,playrandomsong);
 }
 function playrandomsong(e:Event)
 {
 playsong();
 }
```

I know how to export the MP3s for AS (I think) but I have no idea how to make them play randomly, forever.  Also, not sure if garbage collection might become an issue.  Hopefully someone can dumb it down for me, as I'm completely unfamiliar with ActionScript.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> When I play back the SWF locally off my computer's hard drive, the playback is smooth, but when I test it online, things start to get choppy

This raises a big flag hinting that the problem exists with downloading the file.

These two lines of code are going to be executed back to back, which is a problem:

```
sound.load(new URLRequest("parts/"+songs)); 
soundChannel=sound.play();
```

The problem being that sound files won't download instantly. Fortunately, there are events for  download complete and download progress also.

Check this out for a detailed reference: http://www.kirupa.com/developer/as3/playing_sounds.htm

And here is some code specific to your problem:

```
soundChannel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, playrandomsong);

function playsong() {
    ...    
    sound.load(new URLRequest("parts/"+songs));
    sound.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, soundLoaded);
}

function soundLoaded(e:Event) {
    soundChannel = sound.play();
}
function playrandomsong(e:Event) {
    playsong();
}
```

So the order of events here goes

1. Load a sound
2. Wait for the sound to download
3. Play the downloaded sound
4. Wait for the sound to finish playing
5. Load a new sound

Comment: You don't *need* to, but if you aren't worried about the extra 1Mb to download upfront, and you aren't concerned with having to recompile every time you want more words, then that is probably a better way to go. If the user has all the audio upfront, it will play back much smoother.

Comment: Thanks for the info. So, if I am to understand correctly, there is no need to embed the audio within the SWF? Doing so would only require 1 MB or so, since all the samples are very short.  Oddly enough, the sound playback was better when I was using 192 kbps stereo MP3s, but the lower I dropped the bitrate, the choppier the playback became.  At 96 kbps mono, it was barely recognizable.  If possible, I'd like to embed the audio into the SWF so that users can download the file for offline playback.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but the link you provided exclusively covers sound loaded externally.  I am still unclear on how to make all of my MP3s part of a single class and call them up randomly.  I see from your profile that you are familiar with AS3.  If you would be interested in walking me through the process, I'd be happy to make it up to you somehow, but after several attempts at plugging in your code, Flash is returning syntax errors.  I couldn't find a way to PM you, so please feel free to drop me a line at jcwittliff@gmail.com if you are interested.